# how do i to create a popup in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, popup, jsx

This is my PopBlock.jsx file where i have my button in and i need to be able to click the button and open the popup where all the information is another file Popup.jsx how could i make this pop up work

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styles from './PopupBlock.module.scss';
import {getImageProps, getValue} from '../../../utils';
import {ServiceContext} from '../../Services';
import Popup from './Popup';

const PopupBlock = ({block}) => {
    const services = useContext(ServiceContext);
    const [imageProps, setImageProps] = useState(null);
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (block) {
        setImageProps(getImageProps(
          block.image,
          null,
          url => services.content.getFileURL(url)
        ));
      } else {
        setImageProps(null);
      }
    }, [block, services]);


    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <div className={styles.content}>
          {getValue(block.title, null, (title) => (<h3>{title}</h3>))}
          {getValue(block.text, null, (text) =>
            (<button onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>{text}</button>))}
        </div>
        {imageProps ? (
          <div className={styles.image}>
            <img alt="Alt text populated from Acoustic" {...imageProps} />
          </div>
        ) : null}
        <div className={[styles.popup, /*styles.visible*/].join(' ')}>
          <Popup block={block}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
;

PopupBlock.propTypes =
  {
    block: PropTypes.object
  }
;

export default PopupBlock;
```

This is my Popup.jsx file where the inner information of the pop up is

```
    import React, {useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styles from './Popup.module.scss';
import {getImageProps, getValue} from '../../../utils';
import {ServiceContext} from '../../Services';
import Html from '../../Html';


const Popup = ({block}) => {
    const services = useContext(ServiceContext);
    const [imageProps, setImageProps] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (block) {
        setImageProps(getImageProps(
          block.image,
          null,
          url => services.content.getFileURL(url)
        ));
      } else {
        setImageProps(null);
      }
    }, [block, services]);

    return (
      <div className={styles.background}>
        <div className={styles.container}>
          {imageProps ? (
            <div className={styles.image}>
              <img alt="Alt text populated from Acoustic" {...imageProps} />
            </div>
          ) : null}
          <div className={styles.content}>
            <div className={styles.section}>
            {getValue(block.title, null, (title) => (<h3>{title}</h3>))}
            {getValue(block.content, null, (content) => (<Html value={content}/>))}
            </div>
            <div className={styles.info}>
              {getValue(block.information, null, (information) => (<Html value={information}/>))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
;

Popup.propTypes =
  {
    block: PropTypes.object
  }
;

export default Popup;
```

if anyone knows how i could make a pop up for this please let me know thanks the blocks are what have the button on and when they are pressed i want the pop up with all the information in to come up

Comment: Is your codebase using a specific UI library?  If so, I would look there first.  If not you can look for a small library just for popups, which have already solved that problem. For example: [reactjs-popup](https://github.com/yjose/reactjs-popup) or [react-popover](https://github.com/littlebits/react-popover).  You can then consult their API.  If you want to write it yourself, then a longer answer might be needed.

Comment: I am using acoustic for this

Comment: This pop up is one of the components I have made for it the pop up content is populated by acoustic which I have pulled through in both files